# How can I speed up clipping CCSprite

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x

What is the best way to clip a sprite?
I used CCClippingNode but its too slow on iPhone4..
Maybe there is a way to do it? with stencil buffer or with shaders?

I have some CCRenderTexture and I want to clip it with CCSprite, where there is no alpha I don't want there to be an pixel visible, and at once I may have 5-6 such nodes and it's too slow on iPhone 4 and some android devices..

Comment: You also posted this to the Cocos2d-x forums. Shaders would work.

Comment: Clip in what sense? I assume this is not a per-vertex clip? Those are always the fastest, anything involving shaders or the stencil buffer is going to be per-fragment, since the iPhone cannot implement geometry shaders.

Comment: I have some CCRenderTexture and I want to clip it with CCSprite, where there is no alpha I don't want there to be an pixel visible

Comment: In that case, a shader would be the easiest way to do this. Test the alpha value of the texture, and then `discard` if it is < 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Activate Stencil:

```
EAGLView *__glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame: [window bounds]
                                 pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                 depthFormat: GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
                          preserveBackbuffer: NO
                                  sharegroup: nil
                               multiSampling: NO
                             numberOfSamples: 0];
```

See: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/20141

Comment: He will still need to do something like `glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 1, 0xFF);` and `glStencilMask(0x00);` or no?

Comment: Yes, I have done it with CCClippingNode but its too slow when you have too many sprites.. 
I have some CCRenderTexture and I want to clip it with CCSprite, where there is no alpha I don't want there to be a pixel visible, and at once I may have 5-6 such nodes and it's too slow on iPhone 4 and some android devices..